# E-voting: How to hide transaction data on a chain, but still use it for calculations?

Tags: encryption, zkp

Does anyone know if there is any support for homomorphic encryption, blind signatures, ZKP or mixnets for Solana/Anchor programs? I am working on a e-voting project, where final results need to be calculated without disclosing for which option individual users actually voted

August 15, 2022

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically anything can run on Solana, but it might be too heavy or require syscalls in the runtime sometimes to be achievable.

A few things that run stuff sort of related to your request:

https://github.com/Lightprotocol/light-protocol-program uses zkSNARK proofs

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/zk-token-protocol-paper/part2.pdf homomorphic encryption of token balances with zk token in the solana-program-library

the implementation will be an extension in the token-2022 program

Comment: Hi, does this answer change at all with the new token extensions (2022)?